# Ui-Router navbar options not refreshing after login/logout

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've defined a navbar using angular and ui-bootstrap.  There are several nav options which are rendered based on a login state:

- If a user or admin is logged in, there should be a `Logout` option in the nav bar.
- If an admin is logged in, the `Admin` option shows in the nav bar
- If a user is logged in, no `Admin` appears in the navbar, instead a `Profile` link shows.

I'm using `ui-router` in this project, and according to the documentation, a parent state is never refreshed when a child state is, unless `{refresh : true}` is included in the state call.  However, nothing refers to refreshing the state of one ui-view based on state of another.

The main index page of the app has two `ui-view` elements defined: one for nav, and the other for the application content:

```
<body ng-app="app">
   <div ui-view="nav"></div>
   <div class="container-fluid">
       <div ui-view="appContent"></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

What is occurring is when I click on a `Logout` nav option, I successfully log out but the nav options do not change unless I refresh the page.

My navbar template:

```
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" collapse="navbarCollapsed">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <a ui-sref="home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li ng-if="!userState.isLoggedIn()">
                <a ui-sref="login">Login</a>
            </li>
            <li ng-if="userState.isLoggedIn() && !userState.isAdmin()">
                <a ui-sref="profile">Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li ng-if="userState.isAdmin()">
                <a ui-sref="admin">Admin</a>
            </li>
            <li ng-if="userState.isLoggedIn()">
                <a href="#" ng-click="logoutUser()">Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

and controller:

```
angular.module('navigation')
.controller('NavCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, $state, $log, $sce, authenticationService, userService) {
    "use strict";

    var user = authenticationService.getUser();

    $scope.userState = {

        isAdmin : function() {
            return user !== null && user.role === 'ADMIN';
        },
        isLoggedIn : function() {
            return user !== null;
        }
    };

    $scope.logoutUser = function() {
        userService.clearLocalState();
        $state.go('home', {}, {reload : true});
    };
});
```

With the `{reload : true}` param option, I see a flicker in the nav element on logout, but the option visibility does not change.  The only solution that works is a manual page refresh and I'd like to avoid that if at all possible.

Comment: I suppose that 'home' state is active and in this case if you use reload option then controller is not re-instantiating so controller state is the same. Just read it in documentation https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#statereload In this case maybe you can use $location service to reload the page and force angular to create a new instance from controller.

Comment: I just implemented this solution, but it is less than ideal because it forces a page reload, along with JS compilation and DOM rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have tovreload content of your navbar view. It's possible without the whole page refreshing. Use `$state` object. It has `reload` and other methods for manual manipulating of your views

Comment: That is what `{reload : true}` in the `$state.go()` is supposed to handle.  See the last block in my navigation controller snippet for the `logoutUser` function

Comment: Another way is to refresh your navbar data in some other way, because your code depends on this data. And I think you have to reload or refresh your `user` object or just `userState` object

Answer (score 0):

Navbar template:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" collapse="navbarCollapsed">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
            <a ui-sref="home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-if="!user">
            <a ui-sref="login">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-if="user && user.role !== 'ADMIN'">
            <a ui-sref="profile">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-if="user.role === 'ADMIN'">
            <a ui-sref="admin">Admin</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-if="user !== null">
            <a href="#" ng-click="logoutUser()">Logout</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and controller:

```
angular.module('navigation')
  .controller('NavCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, $state, $log, $sce,      authenticationService, userService) {
  "use strict";

   $scope.user = authenticationService.getUser();

   $scope.logoutUser = function() {
      userService.clearLocalState();
      $scope.user = authenticationService.getUser();
      //$state.go('home', {}, {reload : true});
   };
});
```

It is a dirty "solution" but maybe a solution if you do not want to use $location reload.